# Nautilus windows are not focused when launched via hotkeys

Tags: unity, nautilus, compiz

When launching Nautilus windows from terminal, keyboard shortcuts configured in the *Keyboard* application, or via Alt+F2 and then typing /, the resulting Nautilus window is not focused.  This is the opposite behavior of previous releases where the window would be focused, facilitating immediate use.

Is this behavior a bug or is there a setting to make the window gain focus like it did in previous releases?

Comment: It's a known bug in Compiz, maybe already fixed upstream, but not yet in the latest development release of Ubuntu (as I still can reproduce it in 12.04). Haven't found a bug number right now.

Comment: See [Bug 817246 on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/817246).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a *focus prevention* issue.

Launch CompizConfig Settings Manager and got to `General Options` →  `Focus` tab. In the *Focus Prevention Windows field*, put : `!(class=Nautilus)`